# SSRS Report Stuck On Loading After SQL Server Upgrade From Standard To Enterprise

Tags: ssrs-2016, reporting-services-2016

We updated our SQL Server from Standard to Enterprise.  All my solutions were originally built in Visual Studio 17 (SSTD) and deployed as VS 8, 12, 14. I updated one of my reports and deployed it as VS16. The report worked at first, then became really laggy.  All other reports were working fine.  I attempted to open the solution using Blend, but it indicated it was incompatible.  When I attempted to reopen the solution using VS 17 (SSDT), it indicated the same error (incompatible). Now I am unable to open any solution using VS 17 (SSDT) nor Blend. They all indicate that they are incompatible. I noticed that the Microsoft Reporting Services Projects extension (Ver 2.5.9) was disabled. I re-enabled it, but it did not resolve the issue. Not sure what to try next...…..

Answer (score 0):

Update: After trying a multitude of possible solutions that  worked for others, this was a really simple fix (which I found by accident).  If anyone receives an 'incompatibility', I would definitely suggest this, prior to any other attempt.
I opened VS 17 (SSDT) and attempted to load my solution.
In the Solution Explorer, the Solution is listed with (incompatible) in brackets.
Right Click on the Solution Name and look for the 'Resolve Issues' option.
That was it. Resolved!
Hope this helps anyone who receives the same issue.